# Kangaroo tag needs removing

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I see a [question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27582/keep-getting-air-in-the-fuel-line) has been asked using the [kangaroo](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kangaroo) tag for a type of Renault Van.

I'm pretty certain that is a Kangoo, not a Kangaroo, so maybe the tag was created in error. I have edited the question to use [kangoo](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kangoo) but the [kangaroo](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kangaroo) tag probably needs removing.

Comment: There aren't any questions against it now, so the system *should* remove it after a period of inactivity, right? I agree it's confusing ... and I'm probably the one who created it, lol.

Comment: Grand - I assumed it was an autocomplete. I only spotted it because someone had added tag wiki, and I wasn't sure if that would make it stick around :-)

Comment: I put a second reject on the wiki add myself ... hopefully that and it having no questions on it will make it go away. If it doesn't, I'm sure Bob or Larry can take care of it.